# How can I decrease the Krafft temperature of an hexadecyl sulfate surfactant?

Tags: solubility, surfactants

I need to prepare an anionic surfactant from a treatment of cetyl alcohol (hexadecanol) and $\ce{H2SO4}$, and then neutralize it using $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{NH3}$; but sodium hexadecyl sulfate has a standard [Krafft temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krafft_temperature) of around 45 degrees Celsius, which is too high for our purposes.

Is it possible to reduce the Krafft temperature to room temperature by adding electrolytes, solvents or modifying counter-ions?